# How to prevent empty element in XSD while requiring an attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am validating an XML document with the below XSD, and I want to ensure that the value of `reportPath` is not empty.

Here is my current XSD..

```
    <xs:element name="reportPath">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Example:

I want my XSD validator to return false when no value is present in `reportPath`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="ReportAutomation"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="ReportAutomation CommandLine.xsd">
  <templatePath Name="sourcePath">C:\Users\vm821231 Documents\sdtwetrwer.docx</templatePath>
  <reportPath Name="destPath"></reportPath>
  <filter Name="filters">ProjectName=PAL Controller;FolderName=Regression 2 Protocols\!03 Controller 3: Pump Operation;</filter>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<xs:minLength>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict the length to be at least 1 character via `<xs:minLength value="1"/>` (as Ken White mentioned in the comments).

Here's how it all fits together for your XML sample, including how to use `xs:restriction` while concurrently requiring the `Name` attribute

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ra="ReportAutomation"
           targetNamespace="ReportAutomation"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="configuration">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="templatePath" type="ra:namedNonEmptyType"/>
        <xs:element name="reportPath" type="ra:namedNonEmptyType"/>
        <xs:element name="filter" type="ra:namedNonEmptyType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="namedNonEmptyType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="ra:nonEmptyString">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The key point being that you have to do it in two steps - you must declare a named `simpleType` that restricts `xs:string` to apply the `minLength` restriction, and then make the `complexType` extend that.  You can't apply the simple type facets and the complex type attributes in a single declaration.

Comment: Thank for the help full answer..!!